# What does Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 573 mean?

Tags: smtp, sendmail, ruby-on-rails

I am using sendmail to send mail from my Rails application. But, there seems to be a error happening while sending mails to a specific user domain. The error from /var/mail/*** is as follows:

```
Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:46 GMT
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON@*****>
Message-Id: <201110111633.p9BGXkpR010310@******>
To: <****@*****>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
        boundary="p9BGXkpR010310.1318350826/******"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)
This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--p9BGXkpR010310.1318350826/*******

The original message was received at Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:42 GMT
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<****@{domain}.com>
    (reason: 573 ********@****** failed to route the address)
<*****@{domain}.com>
    (reason: 573 *******@****** failed to route the address)
<*****@{domain}.com>
    (reason: 573 *******@******* failed to route the address)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to *********.com.1.0001.arsmtp.com.:
>>> MAIL From:<*******@*******> SIZE=1273
<<< 573 ********@********* failed to route the address
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable

--p9BGXkpR010310.1318350826/*******
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; StreetSense
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:42 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; ****@*******.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 573 *******@******* failed to route the address
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:46 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; *******@********.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 573 *******@******** failed to route the address
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:46 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; ******@*********.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 573 *****@******** failed to route the address
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:46 GMT
```

The bounced back emails are all from the same domain, and mails are being successfully sent to other domains. When I looked for SMTP 573 diagnostic codes, I got this `"573 Internal server error, IP address related."`. But I dont know what it means. Can anyone help me?

I ran these commands and I run it and got the following outputs:

```
# dig streetsense.com MX

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5 <<>> xxxxx.com MX
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 61139
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxxxx.com.     IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
xxxxx.com.  3600    IN  MX  10 xxxxx.com.1.0001.arsmtp.com.
xxxxxx.com. 3600    IN  MX  20 xxxxx.com.2.0001.arsmtp.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xxxxx.com.  155394  IN  NS  ns04.ntiva.net.
xxxxx.com.  155394  IN  NS  ns01.ntiva.net.
xxxxx.com.  155394  IN  NS  ns02.ntiva.net.
xxxxx.com.  155394  IN  NS  ns03.ntiva.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns01.ntiva.net.     147 IN  A   xxx.xx.xx.xxx
ns02.ntiva.net.     147 IN  A   xxx.xx.xx.xxx
ns03.ntiva.net.     147 IN  A   xxx.xx.xx.xxx
ns04.ntiva.net.     147 IN  A   xxx.xx.xx.xxx

;; Query time: 45 msec
;; SERVER: xxx.xxx.x.x#xx(xxx.xxx.x.x)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 11 18:08:23 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 262
```

ping also seem to be working:

```
# ping xxxxxxx.com
PING xxxxxxxx.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx) xx(xx) bytes of data.
64 bytes from linux06.ntiva.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=29.0 ms
64 bytes from linux06.ntiva.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from linux06.ntiva.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from linux06.ntiva.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=27.4 ms
```

Can anyone help me to find the issue?

Comment: Status 573 isn't listed in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt (the current SMTP definition): it is a vendor extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the server encountered an error internally in it's processing that is somehow related to your IP address. Ping is irrelevant - as is what you ate for breakfast. Obviously - the message was not delivered to the server.

Could be a way to tell you to get lost (as in: IP address blacklisted for some reason). Could be a failure to do anything - that will be visible on some error log on the server. Not your problem unless you (a) suspect you are blacklisted or (b) are the server operator so you can check and fix.

Comment: Hi..the emails are not sent and the domain to which the mails are not send is the major customers of my site. This has been a major headache for me for the past week. And I have full access to the server

Comment: Well, then start debugging it on the server. And the emails are sent - the recipient server just does not say "I got it", he says "sorry, internal error". Start on the server - any non totally stupid server will have an error log showing what is behind this error.

Comment: you mean I have to start debugging on the recipient server?..

Comment: Yes, This is a SMTP error that the recipuient server tells your sender. So, it is not the senders problem to debug it - the sender has no idea how to even do that. This needs to be done on the recipient server.

Comment: ohh..I understand..but the thing is these addresses are getting mails from other ids..for example, I am able to send mail and they are receiving it when I send mail from my gmail account. They are not receiving the mail only in the case from my server.

Comment: SO what? THe server says "internal error, related to ip". Without the logs you can not know. SO, start debugging the server. Can be any of a ton of things. Whining around wont help you. Beter get to work - log onto the server and find out the "real" error message that must be logged in the server's logs. THen - guesss what - you likely know more. Maybde this is the server's way to tell you that your IP is blacklsited?

Comment: ok...thanks for ur help...it is just that I dont know stuff..thanks for bearing with me...

Comment: Almost empty answer, said nothing

Comment: Yeah. What would you suggest instead of going to the server and doing an admin's job?

Comment: @tomtom - see my answer below. Before complaint to postmaster@ I prefer make all clean from my side. I'm also long-time postmaster, BTW

Answer (score 1):

Any 5xx-errors in SMTP means **Permanent Delivery Error**.

Here you have a triad of session-parameters, which can correlate with result

- From address (e-mail)
- To address (e-mail)
- sender IP (your server IP) or hostname

You have to check all possible variants, changing only one parameter from session to session (gmail test I'll not accept, bc you change both from name *and* server) and analyze answers

During test we'll identify - is it your ban or misconfiguration of *********.com.1.0001.arsmtp.com (both cases are possible)

Comment: I have changed the to address to my gmail address and the server is sending mail without any problems..also I have tried changing my hostname and still the same error appears with the change in hostname...I have not tried changing the from address..will try that and update you..

Comment: for TO change you'll have to save old recipient domain (in order to have session with the same host as   before)... Sory, forgot to mention *obvious for me* detail